# AWS restrict access to Limited Devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have hosted a web application (node.js + angular.js) on AWS ECS service. My requirement is to restrict access to this application to only certain devices and not all device in my organisation.
I am not sure if we can restrict the devices using devices private IP address of individual machine considering they are dynamic in nature.
I cannot use client certification based on this [aws article](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-workspaces-adds-new-security-features-to-manage-which-cli/).

Can somebody suggeset any other way or can redirect me in right direction.

Comment: The problem is you how to reliable recognize (identify) the device. Using client certificates usually the best option to authenticate the client, however - can you provide othet kind of client secret?

Comment: I was thinking of reading/storing the mac-address of machine. But i belive browser are not capable of reading the client machine mac-adress, I tried using getmac.

Comment: Anything what browser sends on its own (like headers, data ..) can be spoofed (that's why the client certificates are one of a few reliable ways to identify the devices)

Comment: Ok, I tried using Lambda@edge on CloudFront events, but Lambda@edge is currently not available in Asia Pacific region

Comment: I was able to use http basic authentication using Lambda@edge